# Developing JSP page just to see the server logs using log4j in Liferay

Tags: log4j, tomcat7, liferay-6

I want to develop a simple JSP page where I can see the logs of a server. This would not be a 
Portlet just a plain JSP, which I can put in the root folder and hit a URL. I am using Log4j.

I have this application as normal Java EE and I am able to run it in a normal Tomcat server 
7.0.27.

But, I don't know how to run it on a Liferay Tomcat server. The problem is how to
patch the `SystemStatusAppender.java` file. I'm not able to see any logs on my JSP and 
where to keep my `log4j.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

`where to keep my log4j jar`

Your JSP is served by your Tomcat server only, keep the Jar either in your Applciation-> `WEB-INF/Lib` or in Tomcat server class path (`CATALINA_HOME/common/lib directory`)

`I am not able to see any logs on my jsp`,

I think you need to open the logfile prgramatically and display the contents e.g.

```
  <%
      String fileName = System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/logs/myApp.log"
      BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream(cfileName));
      String line;
      while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          out.println(line);
      }
      reader.close();
   %>
```